# How to get style coordinates of element in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I have been banging my head at this for a while now so I need some help from the smart guys.

I am struggling to extract the xy coordinates of the 'background-position' value in my element.  To test this, I set this up (css_class = a predetermined css class):

```
var d = document.getElementById(css_class);

alert("1: "+getStyle(d,'background-position'));
alert("2: "+d.style.backgroundPosition);
alert("3: "+d.currentStyle.backgroundPosition);
alert("4: "+d.style.cssText);
alert("5: "+window.getComputedStyle(d,null).getPropertyValue('background-position')); 

test1--> undefined
test2--> blank
test3--> undefined
test4--> blank
test5-->'Object doesn't support property or method 'getComputedStyle''
```

Nothing gives me back the xy pixel values.  Clearly I have done my research, through all the microsoft DOM API references I could find, here (which is where I got the getStyle function (below, but also uses getComputedStyle), searched some mozilla developer forums, etc.
 This is the function I found on this forum:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp) {
         var camelize = function (str) {
           return str.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter){
              return letter.toUpperCase();
                });
            };

          if (el.currentStyle) {
            return el.currentStyle[camelize(styleProp)];
          } else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
            return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)
                                       .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
          } else {
            return el.style[camelize(styleProp)]; 
          }
        }
```

Basically I'm pretty sure this issue is because my IE 11 browser reverts to IE8 mode (says so in the developer console).  Most of these work in Chrome and Mozilla just fine.  I'm testing in IE8 because my customers still use IE 8.  Also, it appears that the server side code (this is sharepoint server which I don't have full rights on) is forcing the page to display in IE8 Mode.

I also tried to add the html5 tag `<!doctype html>` to maybe force the browser to render in html5.  Still stuck on IE8 mode.  Anyways, can anyone point me to a DOM API call that would work and pull out the pixel values in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

I made a test page where background-position is defined in an inline style, and I was able to pick that up in the .style.backgroundPosition property. (I did have to click a button to enable JavaScript, since it's a local file.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=8">
    <title>ie8 test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px outset gray; background-image: url('./Untitled.png'); background-position: 10px 10px;"></div>
    <script>
        document.write(document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundPosition);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of IE11's developer tools, showing the value of document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundPosition]